# Hard disk has no size and is unrecognizable by fdisk

Tags: hard-disk, fdisk

I am using Arch Linux (x86_64), and my 120GB external hard drive isn't working. If I use c/fdisk, c/gdisk or g/parted, they don't see /dev/sdb (my hard drive). Other tools like mkfs work, but spit an error. Output of mkfs.ext4:

```
$ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb
mke2fs 1.46.2 (28-Feb-2021)
mkfs.ext4: Device size reported to be zero.  Invalid partition specified, or
    partition table wasn't reread after running fdisk, due to
    a modified partition being busy and in use.  You may need to reboot
    to re-read your partition table.
```

I have rebooted, updated using pacman, and tried using different OSes (Debian, Venom, Gobo, Windows) but none of them worked. I believe this is a drive problem.

How do I fix this?

Edit: smartctl outputs:

```
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.12.11-arch1-1] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Read NVMe Identify Controller failed: scsi error medium or hardware error (serious)
```

dmesg:

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep sdb
[14246.708362] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[14252.213470] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[14252.213479] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[14252.213486] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[14252.214034] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[14252.214040] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[14252.214046] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[14252.214631] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[14252.214636] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 0-byte physical blocks
[14252.214958] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[14252.215063] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[14252.215068] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[14252.215465] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (0 bytes)
[14252.232204] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Unit Not Ready
[14252.232218] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[14252.232225] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[14252.232596] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[14252.232602] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[14252.232608] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[14252.232987] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[14252.232993] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[14252.232998] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[14252.234498] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

advanced grep of dmesg (sdb, usb and scsi):

```
[32521.781446] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[32521.798646] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0583, bcdDevice= 2.09
[32521.798660] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[32521.798664] usb 2-1: Product: USB 3.0
[32521.798667] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Union Sine
[32521.798670] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: DD564198838A2
[32521.812116] scsi host2: uas
[32521.813764] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Union    Sine USB 3.0     0209 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[32521.815057] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[32531.843903] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[32549.154622] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[32549.154635] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[32549.154642] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[32549.155457] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[32549.155462] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[32549.155468] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[32549.156410] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[32549.156418] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 0-byte physical blocks
[32549.157097] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[32549.157297] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[32549.157302] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[32549.157943] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (0 bytes)
[32549.177074] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Unit Not Ready
[32549.177088] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[32549.177095] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[32549.177856] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[32549.177861] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[32549.177867] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[32549.181122] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[32549.181136] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[32549.181144] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[32549.183199] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

Comment: What's the output of `cat /sys/block/sdb/size`? If it's zero, there's a problem with the controller. If this is an USB enclosure, it could be the USB-SATA bridge. To verify, take the drive out of the enclosure, attach to SATA, and check the size again. Also check `dmesg` for errors after boot.

Comment: `Hardware Error` definitely points to a drive problem... as you did a `grep` (which ignores the output of the other kernel layers) I still can't tell if this is an USB enclosure, or not.

Comment: You are getting a hardware error via dmesg and you've tried the drive with different operating systems. You haven't mentioned what interface you're using, but if you try it with different ports, cables, and systems that you know to work and if it's an external drive, try it in a different enclosure or remove it from the enclosure and use a direct connection to the system(s) and the issue continues, then that would indicate a drive issue.

Comment: Also ensure all cable connections are connected, including power.

Comment: So it does look like an USB enclosure: Repeat from first comment: To test if it's a problem with the USB-SATA bridge, open the enclosure (usually, it has screws, or other ways to open it). In 99% of the products, you'll find a SATA drive somehow attached to some controller board. Remove the drive, attach via SATA cable to mainboard SATA controller, test again.